# Variable naming in foreach

Tags: php

I am using a foreach statement to extract data from a SQL table and am using an array to loop through every single piece of data I need. Previously I just set the variables for the extracted data equal to the array IDs. Now I would like to instead concatenate a string to the array ID names but am not sure how to accomplish this.

Basically I would just like to add "_type" to every single variable name such this it is no longer named $Banana but §Banana_type instead.

I have tried changing the $$val to $$val . '_type'. However this didn't work. I am quite sure I just need to concatenate the '_type' somehow and would appreciate if anyone can help me out.

```
$variablesArray = array(
  "Apple",
  "Banana",
);

foreach($variablesArray as $val) {
  $query = "SELECT * FROM {$tableName} WHERE ID = '{$CI_NOYEARS}'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die('error');
  while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      $$val = $data["COINFO"];
  }
}
```

Comment: Variable variables is a terrible practice, consider using arrays instead. Also consider using prepared statements, otherwise if `$CI_NOYEARS` variable not handled properly your code is prone to sql injections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really need to have variable variables you can concatenate the variable name and store it in another variable like this:

```
$varName = 'foo'.'1';
$$varName = 1; // $foo1 = 1;
```

or you can concatenate without the variable in between:

```
$var = 'v';
echo ${$var.'ar'}; // echoes 'v'
```

But you can see how ridiculously unclear it gets. This is terrible design choice to use variable variables and it will also confuse your IDE intellisense, static analyzers, and so on. Please don't use variable variables. A better choice would be an array:

```
$myVars = [];
$myVars['foo'] = 'bar';
```